# How To Disable "Read" Request Cache In Kendo UI Data Source

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I'm using ASP.NET MVC Wrapper in MVC4 application.

Everything works fine besides one specific issue:
I defined a datasource for Kendo UI Grid, and when the view loads, the read action is being called as expected.

However, when the page reloads, "read" request gets a response with 304 result.

How can I disable the cache through data source configuration?

Answer (score 14):

You are able to set the 'cache' attribute in your Kendo dataSource to false, which apparently (NOTE: I have not tested this) will force the requested page(s) to be newly fetched on every request.

Setting cache to false appends a "_=[TIMESTAMP]" parameter to the request, which if necessary can be parsed on the server/controller side to avoid server-side cache operations.

Note too that you can specify cache behavior per Kendo transport operation (ie, it can be at the level of CRUD operations or for the whole transport).

See here: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read.cache-Boolean

Code:

```
transport: {
    read: {
        cache: false
    }
}
```

Comment: I was gonna change my idea to user Kendo UI Grid because there were some error when changing page index on grid. It was just go back to page 1 when I tried to change page index. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Says above that he's using the MVC wrapper.  This option isn't available using the wrapper.

Comment: Great, It saves my day..Thank you for great research

Comment: @Phil you can use javascript to change the datasource transport options after the MVC wrapper has built (it's not ideal, but possible)

Answer (score 11):

```
.Read(read => read
    .Action("Action", "Controller", new { area = "Area" })
    .Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
```

Comment: This is the correct way to tell your kendoui grid to query the datasource each time it displays the data.  Also not you have to mark your controller action to accept the post.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I tried [OutputCache(Duration = 0, NoStore = true)], I tried refreshing the grid, turning caching off at the Kendo grid level (MVC), but as soon as I made the controller function annotate [HttpPost], all issues (including paging) got resolved. I could have easily wasted another 4 days on this. Arigatou.

Answer (score 5):

You can try decorating on server side controller's action that loads view with

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
```

attribute, for instance

```
public class OrdersController : Controller
{
    [httpGet]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
    public ActionResult Orders(string userId)
    {
        // your code
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

`NoStore` - A Boolean value that determines whether to prevent secondary storage of sensitive information
`Duration` - The time, in seconds, that the page or user control is cached. Setting this attribute on a page or user control establishes an expiration policy for HTTP responses from the object and will automatically cache the page or user control output.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be controller through the Datasource config.  You will have to apply an attribute to the Read method on the controller to prevent caching.

An alternative would be to apply the [HttpPost] attribute to your controller method.  Then configure the datasource to NOT use the GET method, in which case it will default to use the POST method.

Comment: I didn't see any "caching"-related attributes for Read actions in data source wrapper

Comment: yes that's what I meant...you can't control caching through the Datasource config...through the wrapper...you have to specify attributes on the Read controller action that the wrapper is calling.

Comment: As a workaround I'm using `Read` overload with `routeValues`, and then passing a random value for non-existing attribute (i.e. mocking `&_=1234567890`)

Comment: @ZENIT Unless I misunderstand, won't your random number only be set each time the page loads? I used `Read.Data` and a simple JS function to do cachebusting for every request.

Comment: I'd like to get such a capability through ASP.NET MVC Wrapper. I'm able to set "type" of READ, but not "cache" setting